# How to handle "complex" forms with multiple possible actions per field in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working on a `Symfony 2.8` based web app project. To keep it simple let us assume the web app is a simple address book which allows to manage any number of `Contacts`. Each `Contacts` is assigned to a `Category`, e.g. "Business", "Family", "Friends", "School", etc.

It should be possible to import new Contacts in `CSV` format. In the first step the uploaded CSV file is parsed and the app checks if all used categories are valid == exist within the app.

For non existing categories, the user should have three options:

1. Remove all entries which use this category form the import
2. Re-assign an existing category that should be used instead, e.g. "Private" ==> "Family"
3. Add the missing category to the web app. Beside the name additional details like icon and color need to be selected

**How can this be done?**

Let us assume, that there are invalid categories "Private", "Company" and "Club" in the import data. Now I would like to present a form, where the user could pick for each category on the choices described above:

```
Private    Remove|Assign|Create
Company    Remove|Assign|Create
Club       Remove|Assign|Create
```

Depending on the selection, additional form fields will become visble:

```
Private    REMOVE|Assign|Create    Do not import these entries (text hint)
Company    Remove|ASSIGN|Create    ==> Business (selected from DropDown box)
Club       Remove|Assign|CREATE    Textfield: Name, Dropdown: Icon, Dropdown: Color
```

Of course it is no problem to build this list and so switch between the options using some `JavaScript`.

**BUT:** What is the correct way to pass the result back to `Symfony`? Can this be done by using (custom) `FormTypes`?

The problem is, that the data that is returned/posted for each category has no unique structure but depends on the selected action.

How can i handle that for one category a `BOOL` value is returned (delete = yes) while other receive a string (assign "Business") or complex data (name, icon, color)...

Can this be done with `Symfony` or do i have to build my own data structure (e.g. some JSON) from the user selection and post this back to the WebApp?

Comment: This can be done by using form-events/-handlers. It's essentially the same logic as showing a selection that is dependant on the previous choice ( i.e. country -> state -> city selection) using a single form, correct?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found an example where the selection of `sport` influences the available `fieldPositions` (http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) But this is not the same, since the values of `fieldPosition` depend on the selected `sport` but they are always strings (values might be different but not their type). Additionally: How to switch between the different options/choices without submitting the form first?